# How to reverse the order of svg elements

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am working with a svg element which is following

```html
<svg class="layer1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
    <rect class="bg" id="bg" width="150" height="150" fill="#e6e6e6"></rect>
    <circle class="circ0" id="circ0" cx="75" cy="75" r="72" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></circle>
    <circle class="circ1" id="circ1" cx="75" cy="75" r="69" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></circle>
    <circle class="circ2" id="circ2" cx="75" cy="75" r="66" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></circle>
    <script href="index.js"></script>  
</svg>
```

I want to reverse the order of these circles with javascript, which I am currently doing by this way

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

var x = document.querySelectorAll("[class^='circ']");
var bucket = [];
x.forEach((a, i) => {
    bucket.push(a)
});

bucket.reverse();

x.forEach(
    (a, i) => a.parentNode.removeChild(a)
);

bucket.forEach(
    (a, i) => {
        a.setAttribute("class", 'circ' + [i]);
        a.setAttribute("id", "circ" + [i]);
        svg.appendChild(a);
    }
)
```

```html
<svg class="layer1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
    <rect class="bg" id="bg" width="150" height="150" fill="#e6e6e6"></rect>
    <circle class="circ0" id="circ0" cx="75" cy="75" r="72" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></circle>
    <circle class="circ1" id="circ1" cx="75" cy="75" r="69" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></circle>
    <circle class="circ2" id="circ2" cx="75" cy="75" r="66" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></circle>
    <script href="index.js"></script>  
</svg>
```

It gives me this
[image: Snap]

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append(child)` by itself **moves** DOM Nodes. So your code can be simplified.

But for complexer SVG you probably want to **swap** DOM positions, because there could be other Elements in between you don't want to affect.

- Hold CTRL key to see what happens with `append`
- Click to see the swapping version,
  a matter of processing an Array and swapping the first with the last element.
- Note: `append` was not available in Internet Explorer, that is why you see most posts using `appendChild`.
  Modern browsers have loads more DOM goodies: `replaceWith` `after` , `before` etc.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="height:200px">
  <style>
    text { font-size: 2px }
    [y="3"]{ fill:yellow }
    .first { stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.5 }
  </style>
  <rect class="bg" id="bg" width="10" height="10" fill="grey"></rect>
  <circle class="first" id="c0" cx="2" cy="5" r="2" fill="red" />
  <text x="0" y="3">R</text>
  <circle class="second" id="c1" cx="4" cy="5" r="3" fill="green" />
  <text x="1" y="3">G</text>
  <circle class="last" id="c2" cx="6" cy="5" r="4" fill="blue" />
  <text x="2" y="3">B</text>
  <text x="1" y="6">Click Me!</text>
</svg>
<script>
  let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
  function append() {
    [...svg.querySelectorAll("circle")]
    .reverse().forEach((c, i) => {
                    c.parentNode.append(c);
                    c.setAttribute("class", c.id = 'c' + i);
                    });
  }
  function swap() {
    function swapElements(e1, e2) {
      let {id,previousSibling,className:{baseVal:c2}} = e2;
      e1.after(e2); // put e2 after e1
      e2.id = e1.id; e2.setAttribute("class", e1.getAttribute("class"));
      previousSibling.after(e1); // put e1 after where e2 WAS
      e1.id = id;    e1.setAttribute("class", c2);
    }
    let circles = [...svg.querySelectorAll("circle")];
    while (circles.length) {
      let c1 = circles.shift();
      if (circles.length) swapElements(c1, circles.pop())
    }
  }
  svg.onclick = (e) => (e.ctrlKey && append()) || swap();
</script>
```